# React - Parent Layout Depends on Children Content

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a situation where the parents class depends on if the children have content.

```
 <div className="parent">
    <div className="child1"></div>
    <div className="child2"></div>
    <div className="child3"></div>
 </div>
```

For example if child1 is the only child that has content the parent class should be "a", if child1 and child2 have content the parent class should be "ab", etc. Each child maintains their own state, meaning a child could begin with content and through state changes have none at the end. I'm looking at using Higher Order Components and references to solve this issue but haven't found a great solution yet. Wondering if there's a build pattern to help with this problem.

Comment: It sounds like it would be a good idea to [lift the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent and calculate the resulting parent class there, and send down the data to the children as props.

Comment: Where is the child content coming from?

Comment: @AnthonyLiu The children are static and will always be known

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of traditional React would suggest that if a parent component depends on the state of child components, then that state variable should really be maintained by a shared grandparent like so:

```
<Grandparent> //Maintains State
    <Parent> // receives Grandparent state and state manipulation functions as props
        <Child 1> // receives Grandparent state and state manipulation functions as props (via Parent)
        <Child ...n> // same as child one.
```

You'll end up passing functions defined as methods on  all the way down to  so changes triggered on  can impact the state variable on  and the props are passed down new.

Passing functions and state down and up the tree can get messy, so depending on how many levels you have to your tree, and how much state you are passing around, you could take a look at [redux](https://redux.js.org/) to simplify the flow.  Redux acts as a state container *outside* the React hierarchy, making universal state variables readily accessible at any level of the tree.

Comment: Each child has logic to determine if they should render content, which I'd prefer to keep isolated to the child.